# Where does this "magical" transformatiom come from?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

I'm reading Bak & Newman's complex analysis.

And this is the first time to contact with complex analysis.

At chapter 7, after proving Schwarz's lemma, the authors give "magical" bilinear transformation at least to me.

Which is

$B_\alpha(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ where $|\alpha|<1$.

(They say it is useful to solve some extremal problem. and I'm convinced after examining some examples.)

After searching this transformation for a while, I found this is so called conformal mapping. And in the book which I'm reading, I didn't encounter conformal mapping yet.

But that's all I found, and I'm not sure why this mapping has to be defined as above.

Is there any approachable resource?or could you give the intuition or background of which

why it is defined as above?

Thanks in advance a lot.

Comment: This is a mobius transform or linear fractional transformation. Googling those key words should help you find some info.

Comment: Perhaps useful: Section 6.2 in Green & Krantz ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=u5vhseYCcqkC&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: @HansLundmark thx :) what prerequisites are assumed to read this book?

Comment: Some real analysis should be enough, I guess (single-variable and multi-variable). According to the preface, it's aimed at first-year graduates, so it might be that you want to find some undergraduate complex analysis book instead, which proceeds at a slower pace.

Comment: @HansLundmark I see. it's not appropriate to me. Could you recommend any one proper for me? I learned real analysis but not multivariable analysis yet.

Comment: Well, there are lots and lots, and it's hard for me to recommend anything without more context. Are you taking a course using Bak & Newman, or is it just self-study? Is there something special about that book which is not working for you? Etc. But as a general recommendation, I would think it's useful to take multivariable calculus first.

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry. I forgot to tell you about my context. I study by myself, not taking the course of complex analysis. I've already studied multivariable calculus but not rigorous manner. And since it was quite a while ago, I forget most of things I studied. In the book, all but a this type of "popping up something" not natural to me are fine. (for example, giving some mapping which I don't understand the context how they figured out)

Comment: One really nice (although somewhat unconventional) book is Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*; you could try having a look at that. His explanations are very well motivated (and always geometric whenever possible).

Answer (score 1):

In general, on the real line, you can send any three points to any other three points with a transformation of the form 
$$
x \mapsto \frac{Ax + B}{Cx + D}
$$
which is a so-called "projective" transformation (and is undefined when the denominator is zero).

This extends nicely to the complex "line" (i.e., the set of complex numbers).

The transformation you're looking at is one of these. It helps to look at what it does to $z = 0, a,$ and $\infty$: it sends them to $-a, 0, and \frac{a}{\bar{a}}= \frac{a^2}{\bar{a}a} = \frac{a^2}{|a|^2} = \left( \frac{a}{|a|}\right)^2$, which is just a point on the unit circle that's "twice as far around" as $a$ is.

I'm not sure that helps, but at least the transformation arises from a fairly natural context of projective maps.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Mobius transformation (without rotation term). Mobius transformations are the only biholomorphic maps from the unit disk to the unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$ and are indeed conformals as you have seen.

This form is very usefull for the [Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna%E2%80%93Pick_interpolation)  problem for example and you can find a lot about this form and this problem in the following book : Function theory in the unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by Rudin.